# Python Selenium: get_attribute returns None but the attribute exists

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to scrape images from Google images . My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

keyword = "cats"
url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + keyword + "&source=lnms&tbm=isch&tbs="

driver= webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

tags = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="islrg"]/div[@class="islrc"]/div/a[1]')

for tag in tags:
    link = tag.get_attribute("href")
    print(link)
```

This will print only None.

In the page source the tags have no href , I can see it only from inspect element . How can I get the href of these elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cause of error;**

> The href you want needs to be loaded

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

keyword = "cats"
url = "https://www.google.com/search?q=" + keyword + "&source=lnms&tbm=isch&tbs="

driver= webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

tags = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='wXeWr islib nfEiy mM5pbd']")

for tag in tags:
    tag.click()
    sleep(1)
    print(tag.get_attribute('href'))
```

**solution;**

> I clicked on "tag" to install href

Comment: My xpath is correct , those are the elements I want . And they do have a href attribute but it's only visible from inspect element , not from page source . My question is how can I get it . Can selenium do this ?

Comment: Can you try the code and tell if you can get the output you want?

Comment: I don't want the hrefs from these elements . I want the hrefs from the elements in the OP .

Comment: what you wanted had to be loaded so it seemed to me that href was missing, I corrected the code you can try again