# Selenium .get_attribute() is returning None

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, xpath, hover

My target website is https://bscscan.com/address/0xb66e947f49b6811a8bf438040d1582232d3232d7#tokentxns 
[this text appears when you hover the mouse over time info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wmmt.png) 
I am trying to get the exact date of the last transaction in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wmmt.png) (age) when you hover the mouse it appears, therefore I need to get the 'title data-original-title' attribute because it has the date [can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20brj.png) but when I try to get the date with this code it prints **None**

```
data = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/span').get_attribute('title data-original-title')
print(data)
```

```
    driver_path = "browser/chromedriver.exe"
    partial_website_link = "b66e947f49b6811a8bf438040d1582232d3232d7"
    final_website_link = f"https://bscscan.com/address/0x{partial_website_link}#tokentxns"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
    driver.get(final_website_link)
    time.sleep(3)
    frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tokenpageiframe"]')
    driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
    
    data = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="body"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/span').get_attribute('title data-original-title')
    print(data)
```

Comment: What is the problem here? You can locate that element but can't get it's text or it's data-original-title value?

Comment: @Prophet hey, I've updated the question. Can you please check again? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few tries and expanding your question, I came up with the following working example:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver_path = "browser/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)

partial_website_link = "b66e947f49b6811a8bf438040d1582232d3232d7"
final_website_link = f"https://bscscan.com/address/0x{partial_website_link}#tokentxns"

driver.get(final_website_link)
frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tokenpageiframe"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
# For some reason the Info you want to print is in the attribute title
data = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/span""").get_attribute('title')

print(data)
```

If you want to get **all the Dates** from the first page do this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver_path = "browser/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)

partial_website_link = "b66e947f49b6811a8bf438040d1582232d3232d7"
final_website_link = f"https://bscscan.com/address/0x{partial_website_link}#tokentxns"

driver.get(final_website_link)
frame = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tokenpageiframe"]')
driver.switch_to.frame(frame)
# The star in the Xpath is a wildcard, Note the find_elements_by_xpath instead of find_element_by_xpath
dates = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("""//*[@id="body"]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[*]/td[3]/span""")
# Iterate over every found element
for date in dates:
    print(date.get_attribute('title'))
```

Comment: Hey thanks but I got this error now can you please help me out? Unresolved attribute reference 'get_element_by_xpath' for class 'WebDriver' do I need to import something? If I do find_element then it returns none.

Comment: @JosJes i updated the code with the needed imports

Comment: Unfortunately it prints none when I print data even though xpath is correct. Any ideas?

Comment: @JosJes can you show me your implementation of my code example above ?
The Error could appear because of this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62664397/python-selenium-get-attribute-returns-none-but-the-attribute-exists

Comment: I am also checking some stuff but really got stuck. Can you please check my question again I've updated it. Big thanks.

Comment: @JosJes i updated my solution. Should work now, could you check please?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


driver_path = "browser/chromedriver.exe"
partial_website_link = "b66e947f49b6811a8bf438040d1582232d3232d7"
final_website_link = f"https://bscscan.com/address/0x{partial_website_link}#tokentxns"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.get(final_website_link)

wait(driver, 10).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tokenpageiframe"]')))
time.sleep(1)
ages = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(`//div[@class="table-responsive" and not(@style)]//td[@class="showAge "]//span`)
latest_age = ages[0].get_attribute("title data-original-title")

hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(latest_age)
hover.perform()

tool_tip = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="tooltip-inner"]')
age = tool_tip.text
print(age)
```

Comment: Tried it and some more but still it gives None.

Comment: with the code above, does `ages` contains list of web elements?

Comment: Yes it does like this <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="618aca26aa5720a8833fde38151d0dfc", element="46653cd1-8b06-4249-9fa3-f4ee228e79f3")>

Comment: You tried both `latest_age = ages[0].get_attribute("title data-original-title")` and `latest_age = ages[0].get_attribute("data-original-title")` ? BTW, does `age = ages[0]` `age` contains web element?

Comment: Well, I added hovering over that element, getting the tool-tip and extracting it text. Hope now it will work

Comment: Thanks I will try. My main purpose was to identify the latest transaction so it wouldn't send notification more than once with every page refresh which program is doing to check for latest transactions. Since I couldn't manage the stuff in the question, instead I found the transaction time manually by doing current_time minus time_passed. But I'll try your code too thanks again.

Comment: My code fetches the last transaction as the first element in the table. That's simple :)

Comment: I got the error ```AttributeError: move_to requires a WebElement``` but other answer worked, Thanks for bothering.

Comment: Right, `move_to_element` receives as parameter the `latest_age`. `ages` is a list of web elements and you admitted yesterday that it contains web elements. so, `latest_age` is the first web element from that list. It should work! Currently I have no Python with Selenium on my computer at all :) so I can't debug this on my side, just to ask you what happens there on your side.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:-

```
tableRows = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//table[@class='table table-hover']/tbody/tr")
for tr in tableRows:
    print(tr.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[@class='showAge ']/span[@rel='tooltip']").get_attribute("data-original-title"))
```